# Rewrite a URL with curly brackets around a query string value in IIS

Tags: url-rewriting, sharepoint-2010, iis-7.5

How can I replace the query string value of my URL using IIS?
All I want to do is change the value in the **ListId** from the old value to the new one.

Old **ListId** value: 7898D8D3-7FDC-427C-B81D-AE95ADA03F07

New **ListId** value: 32992B8E-905E-47CA-BAB2-846D3E5D399F

Source URL:

```
/sites/techopskb/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={7898D8D3-7FDC-427C-B81D-AE95ADA03F07}&ID=5859&ContentTypeID=0x0100D98D0B04DDCDF84C872D58FFE6AA6B84
```

Target URL:

```
/sites/techopskb/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={32992B8E-905E-47CA-BAB2-846D3E5D399F}&ID=7537&ContentTypeID=0x0100D98D0B04DDCDF84C872D58FFE6AA6B84
```

The curly braces are causing my headaches. I've tried the `%7B` and `%7D` in the expression, but IIS doesn't like it. (BTW- this is a SharePoint 2010 website, IIS v7.5)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use {UrlDecode:%7B} . [See here](http://blogs.iis.net/danielvl/how-to-escape-curly-brackets-in-url-rewrite-rule)

So your rewrite rule will look something like below

```
<rule name="ModifyQueryString" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)listid=\{7898D8D3-7FDC-427C-B81D-AE95ADA03F07\}(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/sites/techopskb/_layouts/listform.aspx?{C:1}&amp;listid={UrlDecode:%7B}32992B8E-905E-47CA-BAB2-846D3E5D399F{UrlDecode:%7D}{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I initially thought this worked, but its not quite right. Using the above as a guideline, I end up with a very long, repeating URL string. Here it is...
`http://www.example.com/sites/techopskb/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&&ListId={32992B8E-905E-47CA-BAB2-846D3E5D399F}&ID=1037&ContentTypeID=0x0100D98D0B04DDCDF84C872D58FFE6AA6B84&PageType=4&&ListId={32992B8E-905E-47CA-BAB2-846D3E5D399F}&ID=1037&ContentTypeID=0x0100D98D0B04DDCDF84C872D58FFE6AA6B84&PageType=4&&ListId={32992B8E-905E-47CA-BAB2-846D3E5D399F}&ID=1037&ContentTypeID=0x0100D98D0B04DDCDF84C872D58FFE6AA6B84`, etc....

Comment: Did you uncheck append query string in the rule?

Comment: Did you try unchecking append query string in the rule?

Comment: Yes, and it wasn't correcting the problem. Does IIS carry a cache for this that needs cleared?

Comment: No nothing like that and i have the same rule on my MVC website and it works as expected.So may be SharePoint is overriding something, do you have any urlrewrite rules on the same site that works? Can you also show what exactly is your rule now?

Comment: Also rather than doing at site level you can do it at server level and see if it helps

Comment: All URL rewrites on the server were disabled the last couple of days because we've been working other issues with the site. After several App Pool recycles and a site restart, I enabled the URL rewrite. I made sure that "append query string" was unchecked. The embedded links seem so to be redirecting and resolving now. 

I can't say for sure what caused this to not work and now suddenly work, but it is working. So I will leave it as-is and declare this a success.

Thanks, Ravi!